# NY state and federal taxes for tuition and no income.?

Tags: united-states, taxes

1. I paid tuition and had no raw income (not just net income) in 2014. Do I need to report both New York state tax and Federal tax for 2014? If yes, how shall I report it, and can I leave all amount empty in the forms?
2. Tuition statement for graduate studies comes with Form 1098-T. Can I carry it over to a future year when I have income and use it to offset some of my income tax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to report both New York state tax and Federal tax for 2014?
>   If yes, how shall I report it, and can I leave all amount empty in the
>   forms?

No. But you may be eligible for credits, which may be refundable even if you paid no taxes. To claim these credits you need to file a tax return.

> Tuition statement for graduate studies comes with Form 1098-T. Can I
>   carry it over to a future year when I have income and use it to offset
>   some of my income tax?

No. Tuition doesn't offset tax, in any case. Credits that you may be eligible to do.